# How to solve `Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/qpidcommon.dir/qpid/sys/posix/Condition.cpp.o` while compiling qpid-cpp within Docker Alpine?

Tags: docker, qpid, alpine-linux

Qpid-cpp has been compiled in a Ubuntu docker image and the current size is 1.86GB:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu-qpid-cpp     latest    7e60a5eabee1   44 hours ago        1.86 GB
```

**Aim**

To compile qpid-cpp within docker alpine to reduce the disk size of the image

**Problem**

Some packages that are available in Ubuntu are omitted or different in Alpine, e.g.:

*ubuntu*

```
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential python ruby && \
    apt-get install -y cmake libblkid-dev e2fslibs-dev libboost-all-dev libaudit-dev
```

**Attempt**

In order to find the substitution packages the Dockerfile was built and when an error occurred the required package that is available in Alpine was added.

*alpine*

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk add wget python ruby cmake build-base boost-dev util-linux-dev
```

Although most errors were solved, the following issue occurs while compile qpid-cpp within alpine:

```
[ 17%] Building CXX object 
src/CMakeFiles/qpidcommon.dir/qpid/sys/posix/Condition.cpp.o
In file included from
/qpid-cpp/bld/qpid-cpp-1.36.0/src/qpid/sys/posix/Condition.h:31:0,                 
from /qpid-cpp/bld/qpid-cpp-1.36.0/src/qpid/sys/posix/Condition.cpp:22:
/usr/include/sys/errno.h:1:2: error: #warning redirecting incorrect
#include <sys/errno.h> to <errno.h> [-Werror=cpp]
 #warning redirecting incorrect #include <sys/errno.h> to <errno.h>
  ^~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/qpidcommon.dir/build.make:2727: 
src/CMakeFiles/qpidcommon.dir/qpid/sys/posix/Condition.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1494: src/CMakeFiles/qpidcommon.dir/all] 
Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2
The command '/bin/sh -c cd qpid-cpp/bld/qpid-cpp-1.36.0 && make all && make 
install' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

**Question**

How to solve the compilation issue `Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/qpidcommon.dir/qpid/sys/posix/Condition.cpp.o` while compiling qpid-cpp within Docker Alpine?

Comment: What is the compile command you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this with Ubuntu and Alpine docker images, and I get the same problem on Alpine. It appears that `qpid` won't build on Alpine Linux.

Be aware that the `Ubuntu:16.04` image is 130 MB, 750 MB with dependencies installed. Compared to Alpine's 5 MB, and 476 MB with dependencies.

So those 1.86 GB are mostly made up of build dependencies and qpid itself. You won't be able to escape that with any other image. Maybe you could purge some of the build dependencies after building to decrease the final size.